# how to print 1 to 10 numbers at text view in android?

Tags: java, android, numbers

i am beginer to android,i would like to print 1 -10 numbers in order like one by one as shown follows

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

i would like to print those numbers like 1 3secs after 2, 3secs after 3,3secs after 4......so on

i have written code as follows to print 1-10 but it displaying only 10 .

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        name=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1));

        for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
        name.setText("hai"+i);
        }
```

please is there any solutions for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work, like this, as `onClick()` is run on the UI thread, blocking it for updates until your `onClick()` returns. While

You can solve that with an `AsyncTask`, where the `doInBackground()` method is doing the loop,
sending the number to print via `publishProgress()` and have `onProgressUpdate()` update the TextView.

Here is [an example](https://github.com/pilhuhn/TurtleCar/blob/master/src/de/bsd/turtlecar/SplashActivity.java#L34) of the usage of `AsyncTask`. Also have a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which also illustrates progress updates.

Comment: hey there is no clarity to do

Comment: What do you mean with "Clarity"?

Comment: i don't have more knowledge to implements using AsyncTask.could please give code to use this?

Comment: If this was helpful, consider accepting this (or any other answer) as best answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function is textview called [append](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). You can this function for the purpose:

On how to use this function:

`name.append("\n" + i);`

For printing them after an interval, you can `Handler` and `runnable` combo OR `asynctask`.

Comment: hey i would like to get the numbers in every 3 secs

Comment: could you please help to use Handler or asynctask implementation on this program?